# can someone explain line multiple local variables

Tags: lua

```
1 function getCoordinates()
2   return 12, 55, 123
3 end

4 local x, y, z = getCoordinates()
5 print(x, y, z)  

output:
12  55  123
```

what does line 4 do? if I replace it with

```
local x= getCoordinates()
local y= getCoordinates()
local z= getCoordinates()
```

I get 12 nil 12

evenif I change the print statement to

```
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

still get

12
nil
12

Answer (score 3):

The function `getCoordinates` returns 3 values. Your `local x, y, z` declaration unpacks those values to 3 new variables.

When you assign `getCoordinates()` to a single variable, the last two values get silently dropped, so all 3 variables get the value `12`. (I don't know how you can be getting `nil` for `y`.)